# Identifying when boxing/unboxing occurs

Tags: java, scala, jit, boxing

Does this following definition cause boxing and unboxing each time `getField1` is called? Or does the JIT optimize this, eventually?

```
def field1: Java.lang.Double = getField1(int index)
```

What about the following definition? Would it avoid boxing and unboxing?

```
def field1: Double = getField1(int index)
```

How can I identify when boxing and unboxing is taking place at compile time and run time ?

Comment: Your question has little to do with type erasure.

Comment: @Jubobs, I made an attempt at a better subject line